# How to solve Terminal error "command not found: jest"?

Tags: jestjs

I have to add jest locally to every single project folder I create in order to use it. I can't use the "jest" command on Terminal, but I can do "npm run test".

```
zsh: command not found: jest
```

Jest Error is installed, but it's in my ./node_modules directory. People have said in a previous discussion post that I should run the command
`./node_modules/jest –updateSnapshot`

However, this leads to the error:
`zsh: permission denied: ./jest`

I would like to run jest on Terminal. Please give some advice.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to run it this way :

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest
```

If that doesn't work, try installing jest globally.

```
npm install -g jest
```

Comment: I've tried both solutions before. When I try the first, I get the error `zsh: no such file or directory: ./node_modules/jest` and for the second, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to install jest globally,
(there are a couple of reasons why you do not want to install npm things globally - for example [this one](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-you-should-stop-installing-npm-packages-globally-1b56b97b70cd)),

you can do:

```
npx jest <all your jest flags or files>
```